# How to handle error message from Dio post call?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, dio

I am a newbie in flutter and having difficulty in resolving api calls.
I am using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library for api calls.
I have made an base class to access all api methods. Following is the post example.

```
Future<Response?> postHTTP(String url, dynamic data) async {
try {
  Response response = await baseAPI().post(
    url,
    data: data,
  );
  return response;
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // Handle error
  if (e.response != null) {
    return e.response;
  }
  print(e.message);
  throw Exception(e.response?.data);
}
```

}

and I am calling my login api in the following way.

```
Future<AuthResponse> login(Payload payload) async {
try {
  Response? response = await apiBaseHelper.postMod(
      '/login', {"email": payload.email, "password": payload.password});
  return AuthResponse.fromJson(response?.data);
} catch (e) {
  print('in repo $e');
  throw e;
  // ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.fromJson(e.response?.data);
  // print(errorResponse);
  // return e.response?.data;
}

    AuthResponse loginResponse = await authApi.login(payload);
```

I do get successful login response. I cant figure out how do extract the message that I receive in error response. I have tried to return error.response but then I end up with an error

I would like to show an error toast with the error response message.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes...
you have to check the statuscode like this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
/// your code. here 
}else{
you can now print the error
}
```